# How I can update using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore without change the Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I did updating my data using NuGet Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and success, but the Id data is changed. How i could update data without change the Id data?

this picture before i'm update the data :

[image]

and this after i'm update the data:
[image]

this my controller code :

```
        public IActionResult Edit(int? Id)
        {
            var DataCustomer = _conn.tabel_customer.Where(c => c.CustomerId == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(DataCustomer);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
        {
            _conn.Update(customer);
            _conn.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Message"] = "The Record " + customer.Name + " Is  Changed Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Hi, did you check that it is updated on Id, or "it is inserted another record to database"?

Comment: For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the Modified state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Added state. This helps ensure new entities will be inserted, while existing entities will be updated. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-update(system-object))

Comment: Hi,@Rizal Maulana, Are you sure that when you change the ID value, the database is changing the current record's Id value instead of adding a new record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the customer object you are sending from the edit page is missing the ID or it is giving default int value '0'.

You should use this below code in your form if you are not already doing that.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CustomerId" />
```

Give the reference correctly inside asp-for="HERE" and it should work.